# Pyspark, update value in multiple rows based on condition

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame that looks as below (there are in total about 20 different codes, each represented by a letter), now I want to update the data frame by adding a description to each of the codes. How can I achieve this?

```
----------------------
| Code  | Description|
----------------------
|  A    |     NULL   |
|  B    |     NULL   |
|  C    |     NULL   |
| ...   |            |
----------------------
```

Comment: do you have the descriptions stored somewhere? if so, where? if not, you'd have to write case whens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comibnation of withColumn and case/when

```
.withColumn(
    "Description",
    F.when(F.col("Code") == F.lit("A"), "Code A description").otherwise(
        F.when(F.col("Code") == F.lit("B"), "Code B description").otherwise(
           ....
    ),
)
```

Other option is to create second df with columns code and description and join it to your initial df

Comment: `when().otherwise()` construct can be chained with multiple whens. e.g., `func.when().when().when().otherwise()`

Comment: sure, fair point, thx